# Regex for finding AMD Define calls in combined file

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a combined bundle of AMD modules meaning a file look like:

```
define("somename",[...],function(){})
define("somename1",[...],function(){})
define("somename2",[...],function(){})
define("somename3",[...],function(){})
```

I am looking for a regex that can extract all the names, `["somename","somename1","somename2","somename3"]` for a grunt task.

My failing attemt is `define\("(.*)",(.*?)\)`

Comment: make `"(.*)"` non-greedy: `"(.*?)"` or use: `"([^"]*)"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var text = document.querySelector("#text").textContent; //get text from textarea

var myRegexp = /(?:define\(")(.*?)(?=",)/g; //define the match include the global flag
var stringMatch = []; //set up an empty array
match = myRegexp.exec(text);

while (match != null) {
  stringMatch.push(match[1]); //use the second capture group [1]
  match = myRegexp.exec(text); //iterate the next match
}

document.body.innerHTML += JSON.stringify(stringMatch);
```

```html
<textarea id="text" style="width:400px; height: 100px">
  define("somename",[...],function(){}) define("somename1",[...],function(){}) define("somename2",[...],function(){}) define("somename3",[...],function(){})
</textarea>
```

This regex should do the trick:

```
(?:define\(")(.*?)(?=",)
```

- `(?:\(")` matches but doesn't capture `define("`
- `(.*?)` find everything between `define("`...`",` but stop at `",` because of non greedy operator `?`
- `(?=",)` only match a pattern with this lookahead, don't include the lookahead in the group.

Your pattern is stored in the first captured group `$1`.